# Insert image directory into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problems getting PHP to insert the image path or directory into MySQL database. Instead of the path and name of the image, it is only storing the image name. Also I am renaming the image to match the title of the item it is stored under (e.g. Blue car - title, Blue car - image name). Instead of uploading the new image name it is only storing the original image name.

This is my code for renaming and uploading the image etc.:

```
// The directory that will recieve the uploaded file
$dir = 'uploads/';

//variables for images
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);        

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (strlen($title)>0 && strlen($description)>0) {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $dir . "/" . $title ."." . $extension);


            // Query database and insert data into item table
            $itemQry = 'INSERT INTO items (title, picture, startPrice, category, description, quantity, location, sellingFormat, duration, paymentType, postageDetails)
                        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
            $statement = $conn->prepare($itemQry);
            $statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', $title, $_FILES['picture']['name'], $startPrice, $category, $description, $quantity, $location, $sellingFormat, $duration, $paymentType, $postageDetails);
            $statement->execute();
```

Comment: *it is only storing the image name* because that is what u told it to do

Comment: $_FILES['picture']['name'] will only return the name of the image(e.g file.jpg)

Comment: how do I change this?

Comment: please do not use just the extension to check. Use the mime-type instead. What you have can easily be spoofed

Comment: after move_uploaded_file you need to get the path by 
`$file_path = $dir. basename($_FILES["picture"]['name']);` then save $file_path

Comment: Excellent that is now saving the path. Only it is still only saving the original image name, not the new image name.

Comment: then change the name before saving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
// The directory that will recieve the uploaded file
$dir = 'uploads/';

//variables for images
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["picture"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);        

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if ((strlen($title) > 0) && (strlen($description) > 0)) {
        $newFilePath = $dir . "/" . $title . "." . $extension;
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['picture']['tmp_name'], $newFilePath);

        // Query database and insert data into item table
        $itemQry = 'INSERT INTO items 
            (title, picture, startPrice, category, description,
             quantity, location, sellingFormat, duration, 
             paymentType, postageDetails) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';

        $statement = $conn->prepare($itemQry);
        $statement->bind_param('sssssssssss', $title, $newFilePath, 
                        $startPrice, $category, $description, 
                        $quantity, $location, $sellingFormat, 
                        $duration, $paymentType, $postageDetails);

        $statement->execute();
    }
}
```

Note: Here I have used `$newFilePath` as a new variable which keeps the path and the new file name and using the same to insert into DB. Hope this helps you :).

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!!

Comment: Glad that it helped! :) but yes, as of @Akin, "please do not use just the extension to check. Use the mime-type instead. What you have can easily be spoofed". Take care of these thing.